# problemas con password verify

Tags: php, mysql, login, hash

buen dia tengo una duda
mi problema es al momento de consultar la llave hash en mi login
solo me manda un INT y no me deja logearme correctamente
lo que intento es acceder a mi llave hash de  mi tabla registro y esta asu vez me diga que nivel tiene el usuario si es 1 es administrador y si es 2 es profeso
pongo ejemplo de llave hash
$2y$10$CLzoXY7wtoTFyqAxDi3pVOqCUCeLuthiEAfi2tc76lFNxgNYqCbqu

```
   <?php
include ("conecta.php");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error connecting to database. ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
session_start();

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['usuario']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion , $_POST['password']);

if (!$usuario || !$password) {
    echo "Both fields must be filled out.";
    return;
}

$query = "SELECT rol from registro WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rows == 1) {
    // Leer consulta
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    // Comparar dato
    if($datos['rol'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("Location: admin/index.php");
    }else if ($datos['rol'] == 2) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("Location: profesor/index.php");
    }
    
    else {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("Location: auxiliar.php");
    }
    // Finalizar ejecución de script
    exit;
} 

else {
    
    
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("intentelo de nuevo O solicita registro");
    window.location.href="index.php";
    </script>';


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que:

1. Debiste guardar el password con [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php), de lo contrario no va a ser posible validarlo.
2. No debes modificar la contraseña que introduce el usuario y no te va a afectar por lo mencionado en el siguiente punto.
3. En la consulta no incluyas la contraseña, porque se guardó como *hash* y no será posible obtener igualdad directamente.
4. Si el usuario existe, primero verificas que la contraseña es correcta con [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)
5. Después asignas las variables de sesión.
6. Finalmente, analizas el rol y rediriges a donde corresponda.

```
<?php
include ("conecta.php");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error connecting to database. ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
session_start();

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['usuario']);
// No hagas modificaciones al password que tecleó el usuario
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (!$usuario || !$password) {
    echo "Both fields must be filled out.";
    return;
}

// Busca solo por nombre de usuario
$query = "SELECT rol, password from registro WHERE usuario='$usuario'";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rows == 1) {
    // Leer consulta
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    // Verificar password
    if(password_verify($password, $datos['password'])) {
        // Guarda en sesión nombre y rol, lo vas a necesitar en otras páginas
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['rol'] = $datos['rol'];
        // Comparar dato
        if($datos['rol'] == 1) {
            header("Location: admin/index.php");
        }
        else if ($datos['rol'] == 2) {
            header("Location: profesor/index.php");
        }
        else {
            header("Location: auxiliar.php");
        }
        // Finalizar ejecución de script
        exit;
    }
}
// No es necesario un else, ni hacer la salida con echo
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("intentelo de nuevo O solicita registro");
    window.location.href="index.php";
    </script>
```

### Importante:

Valida el usuario también en las páginas donde ingresa, por ejemplo, en *admin/index.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['rol']) || $_SESSION['rol'] != 1) {
    // El usuario no es administrador!!!
    die('No tienes los permisos necesarios para ingresar a esta página.');
}
```

Comment: si lo guarda cmo password hash defaul

Comment: me sale que no estoy registrado

$2y$10$q3rxPWPnXGnQm0bg5AuGVeCzqY3hYP9gIqoWTuN7ofBolaM

Answer (score 0):

No veo que implementes la verificación. Suponiendo que estás utilizando password_hash(), prueba algo así:

`$pass = $password_verify($password. $tu_hash);`
`$query = "SELECT rol FROM registro WHERE usuario=".$usuario." AND password=".$pass;`